# Filter one element of a list

Tags: r, list, filtering, subset

I have a list:

```
name_lst <- list(one = c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "Kramer"), 
                 two = c("Jerry", "Kramer", "George", "Elaine"))
```

I would like to remove "Kramer" from `name_lst[[SOME_VECTOR]]`, but return the rest of the list.  Would like the output to be:

```
name_lst
$one
[1] "John"  "Paul" "Ringo"
$two
[1] "Jerry"  "Kramer"  "George"  "Elaine"
```

Ideally I would be able to remove a whole group of names, not just "Kramer" (e.g., `! %in% c("George", "Kramer")`.  I have tried:

```
name_lst[name_lst[1] != "Kramer"]
name_lst[name_lst[[1]] != "Kramer"]
name_lst[name_lst$one != "Kramer"]
name_lst[!(name_lst$one %in% "Kramer")]
name_lst[[name_lst[1] != "Kramer"]]
name_lst[[name_lst[[1]] != "Kramer"]]
name_lst[[name_lst$one != "Kramer"]]
name_lst[[!(name_lst$one %in% "Kramer")]]
```

These all return errors or the same list without any changes.

Comment: The answer is good for this particular problem. The general approach for "do something to every element of a list" is (1) write a function that does it too a single element, (2) `lapply(your_function, your_list)`.

Comment: @Gregor I am well aware of this.  `lapply` on a list is well documented with questions and answers.  I only want to run this on a single element, as the title implies.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @Gregor, I think you've got the order of `your_function` and `your_list` muddled up there. Unless you specify `X=` and `FUN=`, I think `your_list` needs to be first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the element you want to look within, then filter and reassign to that particular list element:

```
name_lst[["one"]] <- 
    name_lst[["one"]][!(name_lst[["one"]] %in% c("Kramer", "SomeoneElse"))]

name_lst
#$one
#[1] "John"   "Paul"   "Ringo"  
#
#$two
#[1] "Jerry"  "Kramer"  "George" "Elaine"
```

---

If, as in the comment, you do not want to perform the reassignment but want to get a new object instead, using `purrr::map_if` is one way to go.

```
library(purrr)
NEW_NAME <- name_lst %>%
    map_if(.p = names(.) == "two", ~ .[!(. %in% c("Kramer", "SomeoneElse"))])
# OR, without pipes:
NEW_NAME <- map_if(name_lst,
                   names(name_lst) == "two",
                   ~ .x[!(.x %in% c("Kramer", "SomeoneElse"))])
```

Comment: Nice, I think this will be helpful for people to reference as no websites I've seen show how to do it.  Can you do this in a pipeline'ish way as well? I.e., `name_lst %>% FILTER_A_SPECIFIC_VECTOR %>% SOMETHING_ELSE`?  And can you do it without specifying the element on the front end of `<-`? I.e., `NEW_NAME <- name_lst[FILTER_A_SPECIFIC_VECTOR]`?

Comment: Here's the pipe-iest thing I could come up with, and I put the reassignment on the back end with `->`:  `name_lst %>% \`[[\`("two") %>% \`[\`(!. %in% c("Kramer", "SomeoneElse")) -> name_lst[["two"]]`.  I know that's probably not what you meant...  I'm not sure if there's a nice way to use this approach without the explicit reassignment or use of the global assignment operator, but it seems you want a new object, not reassignment.  You could, however, use `purrr::map_if`:  `name_lst %>% purrr::map_if(.p = names(.) == "two", ~ .[!(. %in% c("Kramer", "SomeoneElse"))])`.

Comment: Yes, that's some fancy subsetting!  The `map_if` is exactly what I was looking for, been spending too much time trying to figure out that `list` (and `data.frame`) subset syntax with `map` functions.  Throw that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not adding much to @Jota's answer, just a different way. If you want to specify the element / elements to work on, and have the option of doing so to more than one element, you can use `lapply`, but only apply to specific elements.

Adding a third list item, just so we can work on two elements, rather than one.

```
name_lst <- list(one = c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "Kramer"), 
                 two = c("Jerry", "Kramer", "George", "Elaine"),
                 three = c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "Kramer", "George"))
```

Set the parameters up first, because I think code tends to read nicer this way.

```
names <- c( "George", "Kramer" )
elements <- c( 1, 3 )
```

Apply the `names` filter to the specified `elements` of the list.

```
library( magrittr )

name_lst[ elements ] %<>%
  lapply( function(x) x[!( x %in% names )] )
```

Output:

```
name_lst
# $one
# [1] "John"  "Paul"  "Ringo"
# 
# $two
# [1] "Jerry"  "Kramer" "George" "Elaine"
# 
# $three
# [1] "John"  "Paul"  "Ringo"
```